# How to test a component with websocket scope?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-websocket

I'm trying to build a simple test of a simple component marked with websocket scope. The problem is that I get this error:

> Scope 'websocket' is not active for the current thread;

Which makes sense, because I'm using a simulated WebSocket client to perform a login, and on the client side context of the Spring app the websocket session created by the client has no impact.

What is the proper way to test websocket scoped components?

Component class:

```
@Service
@Scope(scopeName = "websocket", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class TrackerService {
    
    private final ConcurrentMap<String, Collection<Geolocation>> vehicleBeingTracked = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void startTracking(String plateSequence) {
        vehiclesBeingTracked.put(plateSequence, new ArrayList<>());
    }

    public void stopTracking(String plateSequence) {
        vehiclesBeingTracked.remove(plateSequence);
    }

    public void spotVehicle(String plateSequence, Geolocation geo) {
        vehiclesBeingTracked.get(plateSequence).add(geo);
    }

    public boolean isBeingTracked(String plateSequence) {
        return vehiclesBeingTracked.containsKey(plateSequence);
    }

}
```

Controller class:

```
@Controller
@MessageMapping("/operational/tracker")
public class TrackerController {

    @Autowired
    private TrackerService trackerService;

    @MessageMapping("/plate/{plateSequence}/track.start")
    public void startTracking(@DestinationVariable("plateSequence") String plateSequence) {
        trackerService.startTracking(plateSequence);
    }

}
```

Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = UnifyApplication.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class TrackerTest {

    @Autowired
    private TrackerService trackerService;

    @Test
    public void startTracking() {
        TrackerClient client = new TrackerClient("ws://localhost:9050/operational/websocket", "admin", "admin");
        client.connectAndWait();
        client.send("/operational/tracker/plate/ABC1234/track.start");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);

        boolean result = trackerService.isBeingTracked("ABC1234"); // Here is the error
        Assert.assertTrue(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us a little code of yours. Have you created your websocket with configuration extending with AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer? Which client are you using? There is a built in client called WebSocketStompClient if you are using stomp

Comment: Yes, actually the system works just great. I was using singleton scope and some static references. Now I'm refactoring the code to use websocket scope, but I'm stuck on this kind of test.

Comment: Ofcourse it will fail, as the test doesn't run in the web socket scope. It is only available from inside an active web socket connection which your test case isn't. So you need to find a different way of testing. You might want to use a mock instead of the actual scoped object, instead of `@Autowired` use `@MockBean`.

Comment: But the websocket scoped service needs to be tested anyway. So, how could it be done? Is there any way to get the session context in the testing thread?

Answer (score 0):

Try to spy the trackerService service with the following code inside test class:

```
@SpyBean
private TrackerService trackerService;

@Test
public void startTracking() {
    TrackerClient client = new 

    TrackerClient("ws://localhost:9050/operational/websocket", "admin", "admin");
    client.connectAndWait();
    client.send("/operational/tracker/plate/ABC1234/track.start");
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);

    boolean result = Mockito.verify(trackerService).isBeingTracked("ABC1234");
    Assert.assertTrue(result);
}
```

Updated answer:

```
@MockBean
private TrackerService trackerService;

@Test
public void startTracking() {

    Mockito.doAnswer((Answer<Object>) invocationOnMock -> {
        Object[] args = invocationOnMock.getArguments();
        assertEquals("ABC1234", invocationOnMock.getArgument(0));
        return null;

    }).when(sessionTracker).sessionDestroyed(Mockito.any());

    TrackerClient client = new 

    TrackerClient("ws://localhost:9050/operational/websocket", "admin", "admin");
    client.connectAndWait();
    client.send("/operational/tracker/plate/ABC1234/track.start");
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry to hear that! You can also try to completely mock the service this time. I'll update the answer

Comment: This is a valid alternative, but in this case the mocked service would still not be tested.

Comment: This is an integration test to test your websocket scoped service invocation, To test your service functionality you don't need integration test.Just easily write a unit test without bringing whole context